# wiki questions don't show creation date

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, community-wiki, user-interface

> Normal questions show the date they were asked and the date of the last edit.

[image: normal question image]

> Community wiki questions don't show the date they were asked on; only the date of the last edit.

[image: community wiki question image]

> To find the creation date, one must click the "last edited" link, then scroll all the way down.

[image: finding asking/creation date through history]

> #### EDIT:
>
> I think the creation/asking date of the question is way more important than "who" has the largest edit percentage. Plus, it helps to know whether a question has been asked a year ago or a week ago.

Comment: Your accompanying screenshots are extremely offensive. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/why-do-you-hate-freedom/19775#19775

Comment: RECTANGLES??? YOU ANGER THE VIKING!

Comment: -2 for the rectangles?? wtf?

Comment: No mercy to  the rectanglists!

Comment: well, I'm not changing them now

Comment: Oh, it's so **on** ... Freehand circlists unite!

Comment: You know, you guys can edit the question.  If you don't like the rectangles, change the image and replace it yourself.

Comment: @Adam, it's not a wiki. Though I might take down the "lozers" image, as it's probably not appropriate in the question body.

Comment: Here, circles are for loserz: http://i47.tinypic.com/m90pqx.png

Comment: @hasen j - "it's not a wiki" - well, not *yet*...

Comment: But the creation date will disappear!

Comment: The question is tagged "by design" without explanation, what are design reasons. IMHO, creation date may be more important than the name of the most contributor, since it's agreed, that the author is  a Community.

Answer (score 3):

Wiki entries are meant to be timeless.  If the date of creation matters, then the question might as well be closed and deleted as "too local."

However, if a question is valid and truly depends on the time it was created, PLEASE edit the question and add the specific (allegedly important) timing information to it so future readers can better understand how and why it's important to know the date it was created.

Otherwise it's superfluous information that can be readily gained (as you demonstrate) for those corner cases where one might want to know.

Comment: Wiki entries are meant to be timeless, like ponies.

Comment: All questions are timeless. If you insist; the creation time never matters. Old unanswered questions still need an answer regardless of creation time. Answered questions need not display the creation time at all.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's because wiki entries do not revolve around creation dates (like wikipedia, where you have to go into the history to see when it was started)

Comment: Bad analogy. This is not Wikipedia. Even if we suppose it is a good analogy, Wikipedia doesn't show who edited what in the page itself, let alone the person with the highest percentage of edits.

Comment: From the About section: "The only unusual thing we do is synthesize aspects of **Wikis**, Blogs, Forums, and Digg/Reddit in a way that is somewhat original. Or at least we think so."